# Showing Google Maps in OpenERP

Tags: html, xml, iframe, google-maps-api-3, odoo

I wanted to include `Google maps` in a module of `OpenERP`. As far as I know until I use `iframe` tag of `HTML` I wont be able to show `Google maps` in `OpenERP` but in `OpenERP` I have only two kinds of file one is `.xml` and other is `.py`. Now how am I supposed to add `iframe` with only these two file in hand. Any ideas ?
Thank you

Comment: Atleast someone please tell me if you understand the question ?

Answer (score 3):

There is module called **google_map in openerp addons**. Install that module to get the google map inside openerp and if needed make the necessary changes by creating your own custom module

Answer (score 0):

You can try out Camptocamp's geoengine addon. This addon is meant to display data from the OpenERP database in a custom view using a map. It does not use an iframe to embed a googlemap, afaik.

https://launchpad.net/geospatial-addons

Answer (score 0):

In the 2012 OpenERP Days one of the presentations demonstrated how to craete a custom Webclient widget. The example used was a geo widget that could display and address as a Google Map indide a froam view. The code is available [here](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~openerp-dev/+junk/geo/view/head:/README.rst).

Answer (score 0):

This is an example for openning the map in a new link where the html file which contains the html and java script code for the google map located in 
static/src/googlemaps/get_place_from_coords.html

and the following method will be called when clicking the open google map button in the openerp interface:

```
def button_open_google(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
        for place in self.browse(cr, uid, ids):
            url="/tms/static/src/googlemaps/get_place_from_coords.html?" + str(place.latitude) + ','+ str(place.longitude)
        return { 'type': 'ir.actions.act_url', 'url': url, 'nodestroy': True, 'target': 'new' }
```